# Closed Windows Retaining Their Values/Choices

Tags: windows, delphi, user-interface

I have an application that has a few different forms. From the main form I can open a number of other forms, I use the following command to display the chosen window:

```
frmConversions.ShowModal;
```

Once the user has completed what they need to do in that window and they close that window I close the window using the following:

```
frmConversions.Close;
```

However if the user then goes back to frmConversions, the settings that they had previously chosen will still be selected/entered. Am I handling multiple windows correctly and if so how do I stop the retention of data?

Comment: This question boils down to the fact that every object remembers everything unless you specifically force it to forget it.  Just because you hid and show it again doesn't make it a different object or change any of its state. Imagine how rediculous Delphi would be if it did not do this.

Comment: @MoonPunch: A month has gone by since you asked the question, but you haven't accepted any answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends on how you create the form. If you auto-create the form, then it will exist for the lifetime of the program and so will retain any values stored in the form's variables. If, however, you create modal forms whenever needed and free them afterwards (as is the custom), then values will *not* be stored. This is done thus

```
with TFrmConversions.Create(nil) do
  try
    ShowModal;
  finally
    Free;
  end;
```

Comment: i would prefer to see the same code without the with statement

Comment: @Simon, why do you prefer it?

Comment: The snippet above is extremely idiomatic, and I suspect that even most people who normally don't approve of the `with` statement will find it acceptable (I am one of those who *do* approve of it generally).

Comment: I don't like with here but it's personal preference

Comment: If the OP decides to expand his/her code in the future it could lead to bugs. For newer people who are exploring Delphi, IMO it would be better to steer them in a more 'precise' direction, without the with. I agree with Andreas, although the with could create potential debugging issues in the future

Answer (score 1):

IN the FormClose event, you can choose what happens to the form when you call Close (see the documentation and [here](http://delphi.about.com/od/formsdialogs/a/delphiformlife.htm). If the Action is for example caHide, the form is hidden, not freed. And thereby it will mantain the settings.

Answer (score 0):

There are two basic approaches:
1) create the form each time before it is shown and free it when it is closed.
2) in the form's OnShow event, set all the variables the user might change to their initial values.

A way to accomplish #1 is to put a function in the form's unit file to create it, showmodal, then free it.